# sticky table header transparent the table rows while scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, css-selectors

I am currently experimenting with table header sticky. I have achived it but the problem is with the sticky table header become transparent while I am scrolling the table.
[image: the image of my table]

I don't know how to avoid this transparency. Please anyone can help me.

```
.table-sticky {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 79vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
.spread-table th {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    background-color: green;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

<div class="table-sticky">
  <table class="spread-table" #spreadTable>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="line-item-header" class="line-item-header">
          <button class="header-button line-item-header"></button>
        </th>
            <th *ngFor="let spreadColumn of spreadColumns">
               <button>{{spreadColumn}}</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody *ngFor="let lineitem of dataSource; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <app-child-table [items]="lineitem.children">
          </app-child-table>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="line-item-data">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="lineitem.lineItem" [id]="'line_'+lineitem.id">
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>

        <td *ngFor="let spreadColumn of spreadColumns">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [id]="lineitem.id+'_line_'+spreadColumn"
              [value]="lineitem[spreadColumn]?.value===undefined? null:lineitem[spreadColumn]?.value">
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: From the looks of it, the lines of column 1 (white part) have no background-color. So what you are seeing is the lines scrolling over the header (green) giving it the appearance of being transparent. You need to change the stacking order (how HTML elements are stacked on top of each other) with the element's `z-index` (0 by default). Check out [MDN: the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (obligatory knowledge!!). The answer already given should work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Header z-index to higher than the Table body?

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

```
.thead{ z-index: 15;} .tbody{ z-index: 15;}
```

Comment: .spread-table th { z-index: 15;} is worked. Thank you Carlo

Comment: No Problem :-) my Pleasure!